# StartTag: invalid element name Error: 1: StartTag: invalid element name

Tags: r, xml

I have an xml which I am trying to parse using xmlParse in R. I have a number of xml's which are very similar to what I am trying below and I have no issues, however when trying the exact same process using one of my xml's, I get the below error message.

```
a = "productlist1374.xml"
b = xmlParse(a)
StartTag: invalid element name
Error: 1: StartTag: invalid element name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only certain characters are permitted in XML names by the [W3C XML BNF for component names](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar):

> ```
> Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
> NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] |
>                   [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] |
>                   [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] |
>                   [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] |
>                   [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
> NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] |
>                   [#x203F-#x2040]
> ```

You've not posted your XML, but clearly one or more of your start tags uses a character or characters that are not allowed.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to post my XML here, is there any way I can identify which of my start tags is causing a problem? This isn't an issue with all of the XML's I am using, so I'd like to find the cause of the problem

Comment: Sure, conforming XML parsers will provide diagnostic messages regarding well-formedness violations.  If R's XML library is not providing useful messages that tell you the tag name and/or line number, then run your XML through another XML parser first to find the problem.